# Can different data mining algorithms cross check each other's feature selection?

Tags: predictive-models, data-mining, feature-selection

I have worked with the same data set for a little while, using a number of different data mining algorithms. As a result, I have developed a short list of predicottors which are virtually always useful - they score highly whatever measure of predictor importance ( although the order may be shuffled) is used and their use improves the model accuracy irrespective of algorithm used. Is this observation meaningful in the sense of being a solid argument that these are important predictors? If yes, has there been any formal discussion of using different data mining algorithms to cross check?